# How to deserialize Json without property name .net core newtonsoft

Tags: json, .net, .net-core, deserialization

How to map if response comes as follows:

[image: positions]

My classes for mapping are defined like this:

```
public class Data
{   
    public Position positions { get; set; }
}    


[JsonArray]
public class Positions
{
    public string[] value { get; set; }
   
}
```

But it results as error like this:

JsonSerializationException: Cannot create and populate list type LifeMatrix.Controllers.Positions. Path 'data[0].positions', line 71, position 17.

Sorry if the problem description sucks. I'd love to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Your model does not represent your json corretly. `positions` is an array of arrays so your `Data` class should look like:

```cs
public class Data
{   
    public string[][] positions { get; set; }
}
```